# Some way to don't repeat functions in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going to reuse some functions in a lot of models, in rails, so I thought there must be a better way to don't rewrite the codes or don't load helpers inside the model.

So, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can place common functions inside a module

```
module CommonFunctions
  def common1
  end

  def common2
  end
end
```

then include them in your models that use them

```
class Comment
  include CommonFunctions
end

class Post
  include CommonFunctions
end
```